# Not able to start eclipse with a workspace

Tags: permissions, java, eclipse

I am not able to start eclipse on windows 10 it gives error, workspace is opened in another eclipse although there is no eclipse running.

[image]

I have tried deleting `.lock` file in `.metadeta` directory of eclipse workspace, it says : `Action can not be completed because file is opened in eclipse.exe`.

I checked in task manager, there is not eclipse running.

I tried from command line - `del /f .lock`

It gives the error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Eclipse was stuck so I restarted Windows since then it is giving this issue.

Comment: For finding the process which is using your file you can execute "resmon.exe", then click on the CPU tab and now enter the name of the file your unable to delete in the search box on the right of "Associated Handles", now kill all processes shown by right-click -> End Process.

Answer (score -1):

Use Resource monitor to End Process and delete those files.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could add some more details explaining how to do this..